# Theorem 1.40 from Rudin RCA, the last ≤

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW1sW.png [proof of 1.40][1]
I got stuck in the last ≤. And another: how can $E=f^{-1}(Δ)$ dosen't contradict with $E∈\mathfrak{M}$?

Comment: I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Oh, the E in the proof differs the E in the theorem's description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because for $x\in E=f^{-1}(\Delta)$, then $|f(x)-\alpha|\leq r$ by the definition of $\Delta$, so $\dfrac{1}{\mu(E)}\displaystyle\int_{E}|f-\alpha|d\mu\leq\dfrac{1}{\mu(E)}\cdot r\cdot\mu(E)=r$.